# Could someone help me make this checklist-execution dialogue sound correct?

Tags: landing, terminology, pilots, approach, checklist

I am translating from Chinese a dialogue that involves two pilots going through an approach checklist. However, all the information I could find on the internet seemed to be for flight simulators (I think?) and I'm really lost.

Below is what I currently have, and I'm pretty sure there's more wrong than right...
In any case, the speaker alternates every line (i.e. lines 1, 3, 5... = pilot A, lines 2, 4, 6... = pilot B).

> “Approach procedure.” *??*
> “Approach procedure confirmed.”
> “Approach setup.” *??*
> “Approach setup complete.”
> “Speed.”
> “220 KIAS.” *(simply "knots"?)*
> “EICAS.”
> “Checked.”
> “Landing lights.”
> “On.”
> “Spoilers.”
> “Armed.”
> “Autobrakes.”
> “Set.”
> “Flaps.”
> “Five degrees.”

And the original Chinese goes:
[image: ![enter image description here]

And a link to a document with the text content if it's at all helpful: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Q4TmYohNdlmav4DtZmKIazRNP7j5qjIjCnJ0kLboxFQ/edit?usp=sharing

The Chinese text is from a fictional story, and there is a possibility that the Chinese itself is either not representative of how approach checklists are done or only representative of how they do the checklists in China.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you being paid to translate word for word, or do you have creative license to condense at all?  For example:  "The pilots completed the approach checklist.". (*I know you aren't asking for writing advice, but...*)

Comment: @MichaelHall I don't have to translate it word for word, but I would ideally like to have a somewhat similar dialogue structure to the original text (so like roughly line for line, but the contents of the lines don't have to match up exactly).

Comment: I am thinking, though, that I could for example do away with the first four lines if they really don't correspond to or mean anything.

Answer (score 2):

Taking the Descent Checklist from [this site](http://www.b737.org.uk/nnp.htm), which, as a checklist, looks about like this:

- DESCENT CHECKLIST
- Pressurisation . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .LAND ALT___
- Recall . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Checked
- Autobrake . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . ___
- Landing data . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .VREF___, Minimums___
- Approach briefing . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . Completed

This would sound something like this:

- "Descent Checklist"
- "Descent Checklist: Pressurization"
- "Land Altitude 1,000 feet, set"
- "Recall"
- "Checked"
- "Autobrake"
- "Off"
- "Landing data"
- "V-Ref 142, minimums 1,200 feet, set"
- "Approach Briefing"
- "Completed"
- "Descent Checklist complete."

The first line would be the pilot flying (PF) calling for the Descent Checklist; the second line would be the pilot monitoring (PM) responding with the name of the checklist and reading the first challenge. The PF responds, the PM reads the next challenge, and so on until after the response to the last item (approach briefing) has been given, the PM announces that the checklist is complete.

The "VRef" challenge is for the landing speed, which typically is just given as the numeric value and without any "knots" required... we all know what units our speed is in.  Which does make the "feet" part of the Pressurization and Minimums lines seem extraneous, but for whatever reason those seem to get mentioned more than "knots" do. But you could include all the units or exclude them all without damaging the realism significantly.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know when/if landing lights get checked? Because landing lights end up playing a role in a subsequent part of the story, and I would like to somehow mention them here if possible.

Comment: During approach landing lights are typically set on when decending through 10 000ft. Depending on SOP the light status is checked once or more times during the rest of the approach, but they should be on below 10 000ft, night and day.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable to insert "Landing lights" "On"  as another item in this checklist.  If you want to, you could also add dialog that indicates when, in terms of altitude in the descent, the checklist is being run. The logical way to do that would be the PF announces "Flight level 180, Descent Checklist" and the first challenge/response becomes "Altimeters" "30.12 set". That way, it's clear the checklist is being run descending through 18,000', which is a perfectly appropriate point to have the landing lights on.